# Pros and Cons of CreateMockAnything() of Mox (pymox) framework

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pymox

First of all the reason for the question - official pymox documentation:
https://code.google.com/p/pymox/wiki/MoxDocumentation

There is a statement in **MockAnything** section telling **"Don't use this unless you absolutely have to!"**. I'm interesting why is that? Does it have some limitations? Personally I found it very useful.

I have the following situation: I have a reference to the module in my class, the module have a bunch of module-level functions used by my class.

```
import db

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # To make possible dependency injection.
        self.db = db
    ...

class Test_A(object):
    def test(self):
        a = A()
        # Perform an injection.
        a.db = mox.CreateMockAnything()
        # Setting an expectation to any function
        a.db.some_func().AndReturn(5)
        ...
```

Since this is a module I can't mock it with *CreateMock()* because this is not a type. Therefore I used *CreateMockAnything()* which is perfect for this case. I know I can stub module functions with:

```
self.mox.StubOutWithMock(module_to_mock, 'FunctionToMock') 
module_to_mock.FunctionToMock().AndReturn(foo)
```

But I don't like this way because here I need to do two actions each time. It's simpler and prettier to have a reference to the module in the class, and mock it with *CreateMockAnything*.

If I misprint some function name the expectation will simply fail (because the code being tested is calling the correct one), so this is not a point...

For *StubOutWithMock*: if I won't notice some additional db function call in tested method, and won't stub it *StubOutWithMock*, it will call the real code and left some garbage in the db. So one more point to protect my solution - using the *CreateMockAnything* instead of stubbing particular methods lets me to completely cut my db dependency, and I also will see the unexpected method call exception thrown by the MockAnything mock.

So what are the reasons to avoid using of *CreateMockAnything()*?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason for this is that it is usually good programming practice to only use objects with well defined interfaces, where possible.

From what I can see in your case, it's a perfectly acceptable use case.